# ¿Poner las cabeceras para que no se cargue la web en un iframe? Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cabeceras-http

En mi archivo de configuración de spring security he puesto las siguientes cabeceras para que no se pueda introducir la web en un iframe.

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <headers>
        <frame-options policy="DENY"/>
    </headers>
</http>
```

Después de introducir esto en mi archivo de configuración, sigue permitiéndome entrar desde un iframe.

Mi versión de spring-security es la 3.2.
Gracias.

Comment: Te fijaste en el navegador (con inspect) si está llegando la cabecera y el valor que tiene?

Comment: Sí, no llega la cabecera.